# How to uniquely Identifies one NSCollectionview from multi NSCollectionViews in Cocoa Mac Os Development?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have 4 NscollectionViews shown on one NsViewcontroller.
I am unable to detect each NscollectionView Uniquely .
I had tried to implement it by setting tag value but, in cocoa development it says tag property is readonly.
Let me know if there is any better approach or any correction that i can do to solve this problem.

Note:- I had done same things on my ios app with no issue, setting tag is no hassle in ios.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cinemaNowCollectionView.tag = 1;
    self.recentMovieCollectionView.tag = 2;
}
```

[this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2JpG.png)

Comment: i think u can set tag in Interface builder, right?

Comment: @GeneCode yeah we can but the option here is greyed out

Comment: You can use your pointers to compare. For example in your delegate methods of collection view you can write next if clause - `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { if collectionView == self.cinemaNowCollectionView { //do smth} else ... }`

Answer (score 0):

`tag` is a read-only property on `NSView` (which `NSCollectionView` subclasses).

The [tag property documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483248-tag?language=objc) says:

> The default value of this property is –1. Subclasses can override this
>   property to provide individual tags for views, possibly redefining the
>   property as readwrite so that you can modify it more easily.

I assume that `NSControl` already does this, so a lot of the default objects support read/write tags by default.

You can follow what the documentation says, and make an `NSCollectionView` subclass with writeable tags.

Or, as was suggested in the comments, simply identify your views by the pointer:

```
- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
{
    if (collectionView == self.cinemaNowCollectionView)
    {

    }

// etc

}
```